# Input validation - react form submitting without any values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm having an input validation problem thats allowing the form to submit without having any `selectorValue`s added. The check I have seems to only check for input inside the `textarea` but doesn't account for the Add button being pressed.

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5228pp3kj) reproducing the issue.

I'm using `Semantic-ui-react` so my `<Form.Field />` looks like this:

```
<Form.Field required>
  <label>Selector Values:</label>
  <TextArea
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter selector values 1-by-1 or as a comma seperated list."
    value={this.state.selectorValue}
    onChange={this.handleSelectorValueChange}
    required={!this.state.selectorValues.length}
  />
  <Button positive fluid onClick={this.addSelectorValue}>
    Add
  </Button>
  <ul>
    {this.state.selectorValues.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <Card>
          <Card.Content>
            {value}
            <Button
              size="mini"
              compact
              floated="right"
              basic
              color="red"
              onClick={this.removeSelectorValue.bind(this, index)}
            >
              X
            </Button>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
</Form.Field>
```

So in the above, `<TextArea>` has a required prop: `!this.state.selectorValues.length`. This is only checking for input inside the `textarea`, it should check that the value has been added by pressing the `Add` button before allowing the form to submit.

Comment: Do you want to prevent adding empty values to `selectorValues` ? or there is something else ?

Comment: Yes I also want to prevent that

Comment: My answer will prevent adding empty values but i'm not sure i get what else is the problem can you explain what else needs to be fixed ?

Comment: If you start typing a value into the text box and hit submit it allows the form to be submitted without the value actually having to be added via the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addSelectorValue` add a check to see if `this.state.selectorValue` it not empty, if it is just return, this will prevent adding empty values to `selectorValues`

```
addSelectorValue = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.state.selectorValue) return;
    //continue if this.state.selectorValue has a value
};
```

Before submitting add a check to see if `this.selectorValues` is empty, if so focus on textarea.

To focus we need to first create a ref to our textarea.

Create a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to be 
attached to a dom element

```
textareaRef = React.createRef();

// will use our ref to focus the element
focusTextarea = () => {
  this.textareaRef.current.focus();
}

handleSubmit = () => {
  const { selectorValues } = this.state;
  if (!selectorValues.length) {
    // call our focusTextarea function when selectorValues is empty
    this.focusTextarea();
    return;
  }
  this.setState({ submittedSelectorValues: selectorValues });
};

// attach our ref to Textarea
<Textarea ref={this.textareaRef} />
```

Comment: This does work. Is there a way to make it an alert focused on the input in question instead of a browser alert? I will probably need a schema validation like `yup` to achieve this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to focus our `Textarea` when handling validation

Answer (score 1):

After some search ... `required` prop is for decorational purposes only - adding astrisk to field label.

It has nothing to form validation. You need a separate solution for that - try [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/148) or set some condition within submit handler.

Formik [plays](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview#complementary-packages) [nicely](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/SchemaValidation.js) with `yup` validation schema - suitable for more complex, dynamic requirements.

Comment: `<Form>` from semantic ui react handles data just like vanilla react `<form />`. So the use of  the `required` prop inside `<TextArea>` has a purpose. `<Form.Field />` required prop is indeed decorational in the sense you described.